# What diseases could be transmitted skin to skin (massage)?

Tags: dermatology, disease-transmission

What kind of diseases one can get from a skin-to-skin interaction such as getting full body massages (without touching intimate parts) assuming a person had mild skin damages that occur after shaving or pimple removal?

Answer (score 2):

See [this February 1 2022 Webpage](https://www.amtamassage.org/publications/massage-therapy-journal/massage-and-skin-conditions) by Matt Alderton, from the American Massage Therapy Association.

> “Massage should be avoided when the client has a communicable disease,” cautions Grabell, who says contraindications are for the good of both the client and the practitioner. “For example, clients with athlete’s foot can have the fungus spread to other areas of the body, as well as to the therapist. Other examples include viral illnesses caused by the herpes virus—chicken pox, shingles or cold sores—or bacterial infections … However, if the client has a skin condition that is not communicable, then massage can proceed.”

See [*Health Precautions for Massage Therapists*](https://www.medbridgemassage.com/h/clinical-pearl-ruth-werner-health-precautions-for-massage-therapists) by Ruth Werner, ["Board Certified in Therapeutic Massage and Bodywork (BCTMB)"](https://www.medbridgemassage.com/about/instructor/ruth-werner-massage-therapists-public-health).

> ##### 2. Bacteria Are Shared Easily
>
> Bacteria are stronger now than they were even a few years ago, and species like methicillin-resistant staphylococcus aureus (MRSA) can cause long-term problems. Other easily shared bacteria can cause impetigo, pinkeye, and – if the immune system is weak – infection of the lymph or blood. Ask yourself:
>
> - **Does your client have an undiagnosed, untreated skin infection?** If yes, refer your client to their doctor and reschedule.
> - **Do you or your client have open, uncovered lesions (think hangnails, scabbed over bug bites and the like)?** If you find one, cover it and/or avoid direct contact.